# Is ignoring clients data during an automatic upgrading acceptable?

Tags: web-hosting, backups, customer-service, clients

I recently faced a deletion of my calendar and notes data inside a third party application ( Horde ) on my online space.

When I told the web hosting provider they replied that they were doing an upgrade to system software (!!) and that third party client applications are not within their reach or backup policy.
They don't even have a backup of my data.
Is this practice acceptable from a web hosting provider, even for individual clients?

I know that backing up my data is my responsibility but I anticipated that backup copies done by the host would be available when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what happened with your host, generally speaking there should never have been any loss of data - especially when the host is upgrading software they offer (which is usually the case w/ Horde).

Regardless of the circumstance, if the host is going to upgrade/modify a portion of your hosting that could result in data loss, it is absolutely their obligation to inform you of such a possiblility with ample time for you to retrieve and back up your data. Not doing so, and then failing to recover your data indicates a severe lack of communication and integrity on the part of your current host.